# Get Image Filename from Image PIL

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

Is it possible to get the filename of an Image I have already opened from an Image object? I checked the API, and the best I could come up with was the PIL.Image.info, but that appears to be empty when I check it.
Is there something else I can use to get this info in the PIL Image library?

(Yes, I realize I can pass the filename into the function. I am looking for another way to do this.)

i.e.

```
from PIL import Image

def foo_img(img_input):
  filename = img_input.info["filename"]
  # I want this to print '/path/to/some/img.img'
  print(filename) 

foo_img(Image.open('/path/to/some/img.img'))
```

Comment: since you're the one opening the file, why not just save the filename?

Comment: @BryanOakley See my note in parentheses.
Unless you mean, I can save it in the info dictionary? in which case that's an answer, and you can write that up.

Comment: The way to think about this is probably that, I'm writing foo_img(), and someone else is calling it. I would like img_input to be the only input into my function. Is there a way for me to get the filename without adding an input to my function?

Comment: There's no guarantee that the image originated with a file to begin with, you could just as easily use `Image.new`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, But if it did, is that information stored anywhere?

Comment: I wish I knew, I would have left an answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't know if this is documented anywhere, but simply using `dir` on an image I opened showed an attribute called `filename`:

```
>>> im = Image.open(r'c:\temp\temp.jpg')
>>> im.filename
'c:\\temp\\temp.jpg'
```

Unfortunately you can't guarantee that attribute will be on the object:

```
>>> im2 = Image.new('RGB', (100,100))
>>> im2.filename
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
    im2.filename
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

You can get around this problem using a `try/except` to catch the `AttributeError`, or you can test to see if the object has a filename before you try to use it:

```
>>> hasattr(im, 'filename')
True
>>> hasattr(im2, 'filename')
False
>>> if hasattr(im, 'filename'):
    print(im.filename)

c:\temp\temp.jpg
```

Answer (score 8):

The `Image` object has a `filename` attribute.

```
 from PIL import Image


 def foo_img(img_input):
     print(img_input.filename)

 foo_img(Image.open('/path/to/some/img.img'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way how I did it is by using the initial file location:

```
def getImageName(file_location):
    filename = file_location.split('/')[-1]
    location = file_location.split('/')[0:-1]
    filename = filename.split('.')
    filename[0] += "_resized"
    filename = '.'.join(filename)
    new_path = '/'.join(location) + '/' + filename
    return new_path
```